# Create tile groups in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps

I want to group my app tile and secondary tiles.

Is there a possibility to create named Tile Groups in Windows 8 programmatically, or maybe a way to re-organize tiles into groups after they have been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot control / group anything outside the app. the app tiles and secondary tiles fall outside the app's bound.